# How to receive ActiveX events in pyQt5?

Tags: python, activex, pyqt5

I've been using pyQt4. I'd like to convert pyQt5.
but, I couldn't use [old-style signal and slot](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#old-style-signals-and-slots) in pyQt5 because pyQt5 supports only [new-style signal and slot](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#new-style-signals-and-slots).
Therefore, I couldn't receive events from ActiveX.

Please, give me solution.

this code is pyQt4 version.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL, QObject
from PyQt4.QAxContainer import QAxWidget

class ActiveXExtend(QObject):
    def __init__(self, view):
        super().__init__()
        self.view = view
        self.ocx = QAxWidget("KHOPENAPI.KHOpenAPICtrl.1")

        # receive ActiveX event.
        self.ocx.connect(self.ocx, SIGNAL("OnReceiveMsg(QString, QString, QString, QString)"), self._OnReceiveMsg)

    # event handler
    def _OnReceiveMsg(self, scrNo, rQName, trCode, msg):
        print("receive event")
```

I try to convert pyQt5.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
from PyQt5.QAxContainer import QAxWidget

class ActiveXExtend(QObject):

    def __init__(self, view):
        super().__init__()
        self.view = view
        self.ocx = QAxWidget("KHOPENAPI.KHOpenAPICtrl.1")
        # receive ActiveX event. 
        # old-style is not supported.
        # self.ocx.connect(self.ocx, SIGNAL("OnReceiveMsg(QString, QString, QString, QString)"), self._OnReceiveMsg)

    # event handler
        def _OnReceiveMsg(self, scrNo, rQName, trCode, msg):
            print("receive event")
```

Comment: Just guessing a bit, but would you be able to [connect slots by name](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#connecting-slots-by-name)?

Answer (score 2):

I found out the solution, finally. pyQt5 supports signals from ActiveX events.

If ActiveX has 'OnReceiveMsg' event, QAxWidget instance supports 'OnReceiveMsg' signal.
Therefore, I fix code like this.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
from PyQt5.QAxContainer import QAxWidget

class ActiveXExtend(QObject):

    def __init__(self, view):
        super().__init__()
        self.view = view
        self.ocx = QAxWidget("KHOPENAPI.KHOpenAPICtrl.1")
        # receive ActiveX event. 
        self.ocx.OnReceiveMsg[str,str,str,str].connect(self._OnReceiveMsg)

    # event handler
        def _OnReceiveMsg(self, scrNo, rQName, trCode, msg):
            print("receive event")
```